# Show acceptance criteria in pull requests in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, version-control, devops

When reviewing PRs in Azure Devops, it would be ideal if the **acceptance criteria** of the task/story would be displayed in the description (e.g. before the commit messages). This to ensure that all required functionality has been implemented and all edge cases have been taken into account. It seems that you need to manually open the work item to find this additional info.

Can the Acceptance Criteria be displayed automatically in the *PR's description*?

Comment: You might have 0 to many associated work items.  There is no enforcement of work item type, so the work items might not even have an acceptance criteria.  There isn't anything out of the box for Azure DevOps that supports this.

Comment: If there are no acceptance criteria, it suffices if all (and therefore none at all) ACs are shown right? :)

Comment: @CasperDijkstra, I provided a solution for your request. It's not difficult, it's just a little bit complicated, but it is effective after testing, you can check if it helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can the AC be displayed automatically in the PR's description?

The short answer is **Yes**.

First, I need to state that there is no out of box way to achieve your needs at this moment. In the latest [sprint-176-update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-176-update) just released at October 01, MS introduced a new feature, **Customize work item state** when pull request is merged. But it only for the work item **state** not for other fields.

**To resolve this request**, we could add a **Build Validation** on the target branch to invoke the REST API [Pull Requests - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to update the description with acceptance criteria of the task/story.

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullrequests/{pullRequestId}?api-version=6.0
```

From above REST API URL, we could to know that if we want use the REST API Pull Requests - Update, we need provide the `pullRequestId`.

In the [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services), there is a variable `System.PullRequest.PullRequestId`, which we could use it to get the `pullRequestId`.

After we get the `pullRequestId`, we could use another REST API [Pull Request Work Items - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20work%20items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get the work items associated with a pull request:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullRequests/{pullRequestId}/workitems?api-version=6.0
```

We could get the workitems Id:

[image]

Now, we could use the [Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get the value of **acceptance criteria**:

[image]

Finally, we could use the REST API Pull Requests - Update with update the description with acceptance criteria of the task/story.

Below is my test powershell scripts:

```
$PullRequestId = $Env:System_PullRequest_PullRequestId

Write-Host "Current PullRequestId is $PullRequestId"

$url = "https://dev.azure.com/<YourOrganizationName>/<YourProjectName>/_apis/git/repositories/<YourRepoId>/pullRequests/$($PullRequestId)/workitems?api-version=6.0"
$PullRequestWorkItems= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{   
 Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
} -Method Get

$WorkItemId= $PullRequestWorkItems.value.id

Write-Host This is WorkItems Id: $WorkItemId

$Testurl = "https://dev.azure.com/<YourOrganizationName>/<YourProjectName>/_apis/wit/workitems/$($WorkItemId)?api-version=6.0"
$WorkitemInfo= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Testurl -Headers @{   
 Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
} -Method Get

$AcceptanceCriteria= $WorkitemInfo.fields.'Microsoft.VSTS.Common.AcceptanceCriteria'

Write-Host This is Acceptance Criteria info: $AcceptanceCriteria


$UpdatePRurl = "https://dev.azure.com/<YourOrganizationName>/<YourProjectName>/_apis/git/repositories/a<YourRepoId>/pullRequests/$($PullRequestId)?api-version=6.0"

$connectionToken="Your PAT"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))


$headers = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" }

$body=@"
  {
    "description": "$($AcceptanceCriteria)"
  }
"@

Write-Host "$url"
$response= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $UpdatePRurl -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body -headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method PATCH
```

This is the test result:

[image]

Comment: This seems to work perfect, however do you have to run the PowerShell script manually? Or can that also be automated?

Comment: @CasperDijkstra, No, you do not need to run the powershell script manually. You could just add a inline powershell task in the new pipeline with above powershell scripts, then add this pipeline as **Build Validation** on the target branch.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation. In this case, when we merge branch to the target branch, it will execute that pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Having a pull request with detailed information can certainly improve the experience for the reviewer, and since the PR is associated with the commit history the description of the PR can be helpful to individuals reviewing history as well. While there’s no built-in functionality to copy details of work items to the description of the PR, there are several options.

## Options for Pull Request Policies

1. **Require linked work items**: policy does support the option to require work items to be linked to the PR. These do expand out as description and easily hyperlink out to the task.
2. **Require comment resolution**: you can add a comment to the PR to request the author to provide more detail. The PR won’t close until they have fulfilled that requirement.

## Options for Improving Pull Request Descriptions

1. **Pull Request templates**: There is support to populate the PR with default text that appears before the PR is created. This is just a markdown file with a special naming convention so there’s no option to add automation, but it’s purpose is for you to communicate to the PR author what you want before the PR will be accepted. http://www.bryancook.net/2020/06/using-templates-to-improve-pull.html?m=1
2. **Commit messages**: encourage your team to provide better commit messages. If they include the work-item number in the message (#1234) it will auto-expand to the work-item description and link to the work-items to the PR automatically. You can even include syntax to change the status of the work item (Resolved: #1234)
3. **Markdown**: the PR description can be written in markdown format, which allows the PR author to present a good case for their change, including images, tables, etc.

## Options for PR extensibility

Honestly, I’m including these here for completeness sake. This is a lot of code and headache to overcome developer hygiene.

1. **Custom Build**: You could write a build definition that runs on every code change to examine the details of the build and fail if certain details aren’t present. The high-level details of the PR (PR ID) are available as [environment variables to the build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services) (Build.Reason, Build.SourceBranch), so you could use the [REST API to fetch the PR information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) and perform some custom checks, such as the presence of certain keywords or format you expect. You can then associate this build definition as a Required build in the PR policy.
2. **Status API**: similar approach as above, create a build that looks for the presence of certain keywords that your build definition inserts into the PR description. If this text is not found, use the API to fetch the details of the work-item(s) (if linked to the PR), update the PR and post a Status message to the PR. Add the definition of the Status check as Required to the PR policy.
3. **Webhook + Status API**:  similar to both approaches, instead of triggering a build you can set up a custom webhook that invokes a custom endpoint anytime a PR is created or updated. The custom endpoint publishes a status message back to the PR, and the PR policy is set to enforce it. [This article outlines how to create a Azure Function to perform a custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-pr-status-server-with-azure-functions?view=azure-devops).

A key thing to remember as a reviewer, you don’t have to complete the PR until it meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but it's not direct though :)

One of the options, that comes to my mind is assigning an optional reviewer through branch policies:
[image]

You can go to Project Settings -> Repositories -> Automatically included reviewers. You could use e.g. a service account, which has no real identity(or any other account to be honest) and assign it for each PR created for a specific branch. When you set such assignment as optional, you will be able to complete a PR without acceptance from that account and to the PR's feed there will be description added, which could be your AC.

It is of course something assuming you have generic ACs. If you want to add AC based on tasks AC, you would leverage REST API of Azure DevOps and add them each time a PR is created. Requires some additional programming, but it's still doable.